# D3 adding multiple children to the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, d3.js

How would I go about adding multiple child elements to a parent?

This is what I would like to achieve :

```
<div id = "myDiv">
    <div id = "child1"></div>
    <div id = "child2"></div>
</div>
```

This would, however, make child2 a child of child1:

```
$("#myDiv").append("div").attr("id", "child1").append("div").attr("id","child2")
```

Is there any way of adding two children with different attributes using dot notation?

EDIT: How about also appending a child to child1?

Answer (score 3):

`$("#myDiv").append("<div id='child1'>").append("<div id='child2'>")`

Answer (score 1):

And another

```
$('#myDiv').append($('<div>', { id: 'child1' })).append($('<div>', { id: 'child2' }))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myDiv").append("div").attr("id", "child1").append("div").attr("id","child2");
```

**Appends "div" text** to myDiv, then **changes the id attribute** of the div formerly known as "myDiv" to "child1" then appends more text and changes the id again.

Change form of your statements:

```
$("<div>").attr("id", "child3").add($("<div>").attr("id", "child4")).appendTo("#myDiv");
```

With this, jQuery creates a properly formed div, assigns and id attribute to it, then adds another div with and id.  Note that the second addition with `.add()` is properly formed due to the `$` inside there and the id attribute added before it gets added to the first one, then they both get appended.

NOTE: you can also use the pattern above or do simple string for the child of child1 as:

```
$("<div id='child1A'/><div id='child1B'/>").appendTo("#child1");
```

Worth noting this only hits the DOM once which is desired and you can build up the string to append more as well - still only hitting the DOM once with that append.

Answer (score 0):

- You could `clone()` `#myDiv` to a variable, loop up to the number of child elements needed, change the attribute and then `appendTo` `#myDiv`. I know right, kinda complex.
- Perhaps you're better off using `append` two times. (In two separate lines, no chaining)
- Oh wait, you could use `add` (Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w4qnk/)

  ```
     $elemts = $()
     $elemts = $elemts.add($('<div/>', { 'id': 'child1'}))
     $elemts = $elemts.add($('<div/>', { 'id': 'child2'}))

     $("#myDiv").append($elemts)
  ```